# IBM worklight - How to use 2 JSONStore collections in the applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

How can I initialize and use two JSONStore collections simultaneously?

One collection for general collections without password,
And another collection protected with a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple stores with different collections. You would enable password protection, or not, for the **store** using the [WL.JSONStore.init](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_init.html) function. Each store can be encrypted with different password protection. See [JSONstore Multiple User Support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_multiple_user_support.html) and [JSONstore Security](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_security.html).